# wordpress permalink redirect to home page if there have any unicode characters

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, unicode

i have a client who recently change his host server and face a werid problem.
i belive it's all happend for unicode characters.
Ex: 
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/dog-meghivo-430x430.jpg  (it's show a images because it's don't have any unicode characters) but when a unicode characer is avaliable in url it's not showing any images and redirect to homePage.

Problem: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/dôg-meghivo-430x430.jpg (ô)
so i want to know how to fix this .i search many time in google for this topic but i can't find the solution.
Thank

Comment: Use REGEX to remove all undesired characters from the image URL.

Comment: or to replace them with regular characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a new bug on the new version of WordPress. It's happened because you changed your permalink after changing your server. The solution is to Upload your post image again and update the post. It's should work fine after that. But you can try to change your permalink setting's to post id